# "bucket.list_blobs()" fails silently on App Engine flex

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a python function that uses the storage object from google.cloud to download a list of files from Google Cloud Storage.

It runs ok locally, it lists the files, downloads them, generates an output and uploads it, no problem.

However, when I deploy this same function in AppEngine flex, the function fails silently when listing the files. It doesn't throw any error, just freezes until app engine terminates the task after 30 seconds. But it is failing because if I set a try: except: statement it reaches the exeption.
However, I don't see any error so I don't know what to fix.

Here is the code I use:

```
def createTFR(folder_name):
  from google.cloud import storage
  bucket_name = 'BUCKET_NAME'
  client = storage.Client()
  bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_name+'/images')
```

And here it is modified with the try catch block:

```
try:
  blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_name +'/images')     
except:
  print("list blobs failed. raising exception")
  raise
```

Thank you

Comment: Google App Engine logs go to Stackdriver Logging. Take a look at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?resource=gae_app and see if you can see the error.

Comment: I just checked but there is nothing new there. I was checking the logs with the bash command "gcloud app logs tail" and the output is the same, no message for the error.

Comment: I have replicated your scenario and it works fine for me, both in local and once deployed. Perhaps you don't have properly configured the right permissions to access some folders within your bucket?